# Amazon S3 module how does the local cache work and where is it at?

Tags: caching

I'm using the [Drupal Amazon S3](https://www.drupal.org/project/amazons3) module and just wondered where/how the local cache works.  Does it reduce file gets to S3?  From what I can see there is an amazons3 table in the db and I can see information being retrieved from this in the module code, but wondered if the file retrieval also was being cached locally.  The retrieval looks to be fast on second and subsequent retrievals and I wondered if this was being cached server side or whether this was purely browser caching coming into play.  If I clear my browser cache, the image retrieval still seems faster than I've seen before with S3 storage but I couldn't locate where the file is being cached.

Many thanks
Lawrence